# Google LineChart does not display a single value

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I parse CSV text files and generate HTML file with several Google line charts [by a perl script](http://pastebin.com/RyrR6xcn).

This works well, except for the cases, when I have just a signle one value of data:

[image]

The value of 27.4 isn't displayed.

The code of my web page is below, just open it in a browser and you will see the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var data = {"L_B8_MAXPWRCAL_CI0":{
                    "rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"MEASUREMENT"},{"v":27.4},{"v":23},{"v":40}]}],

                    "cols":[
{"p":{"role":"domain"},"label":"MEASUREMENT","type":"string"},
{"p":{"role":"data"},"label":"1142926087","type":"number"},
{"p":{"role":"interval"},"label":"LSL","type":"number"},
{"p":{"role":"interval"},"label":"USL","type":"number"}]}};

        function drawCharts() {
                for (var csv in data) {
                        var x = new google.visualization.DataTable(data[csv]);

                        var options = {
                                title: csv,
                                width: 800,
                                height: 600
                        };

                        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(csv));
                        chart.draw(x, options);
                }
        }

        $(function() {
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="L_B8_MAXPWRCAL_CI0"></div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody please know, what to do here?

I'd like a dot or smth. to be displayed for the 27.4

Is there maybe an option for [Line Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) to enforce that?

Or should I use some other type of chart here? I've tried Scatter Chart, but it seems to want 2 data values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pointSize` to that. Test if the row-part only contains 1 element, and show a dot if it does. In your code :

```js
var pointSize = (data[csv].rows.length==1) ? 10 : 0;
var options = {
    title: csv,
    pointSize: pointSize,
    width: 800,
    height: 600
};
```

Result :

[image]